# How to solve these linear and quadratic equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Ok, this may seem simple to some, but I spent so long trying to solve these equations and I wasn't able to:

$x+xy+y=19$
$x^2y+y^2x=84$

I'm finding the pairs of possible x-y values. (x and y are interchangeable, so if (1, 2) is a solution then so is (2, 1))

Can anyone help with this? Every time I tried this I ended up with some stupidly complicated quadratic relation.

Comment: One solution is $(x,y)=(3,4),(4,3)$. The other one is $x=sqrt(29) + 6,...$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $$z=xy$$
then you have

$$x+y+z=19$$
$$z(x+y)=84=z(19-z)$$

so

$$z^2-19z+84=0$$

You can finish.